# How to solve a cannot GET / error in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm using a tutorial and so added the following code

```
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client

// Connection string parameters.
var sqlConfig = {
    user: 'student',
    password: 'something',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'Raw_Data'
}

// Start server and listen on http://localhost:8081/
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select * from testtable', function(err, recordset) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
        });
    });
})
```

After starting the server with node server.js, I'm getting an error statement Cannot GET/ when I access localhost:8081. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: Looking at your code, I dont find any error. I copied your code to my local, commented sql part and executed. I didn' find any issue. I assume that server might have not started in your system. After you start your server, are you seeing the console log "app listening at http://:::8081" ?

Comment: Yes i see that  C:\Users\Mi>node test1.js app listening at http://:::8081

Comment: @oreo2geek Can you please console.log(recordset) and show us if the connection was established?

Comment: Are you accessing the Express server from the same computer on which it is running?

Comment: @sreehari it returns me an error:ReferenceError: recordset is not defined
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mi\test1.js:19:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1320:10)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)

Comment: @robertklep yes! :)

Comment: So, you might be getting some error in the query. Can you replace the code 
     `request.query('select * from testtable', function(err, recordset) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
        });`
to
     `request.query('select * from testtable', function(err, recordset) {
            if(err){
                   console.log(err);
                   return res.send(err);
            } 
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
        });`

Comment: @Sreehari  it returns me this :app listening at http://:::8081
tedious deprecated The default value for `options.encrypt` will change from `false` to `true`.  Please pass `false` explicitly if you want to retain current behaviour. node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:230:23

Comment: { ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
    at Request._query (C:\Users\Mi\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1330:37)
    at Request._query (C:\Users\Mi\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:526:11)
    at Request.query (C:\Users\Mi\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1266:12)
    at C:\Users\Mi\test1.js:23:17
    at _poolCreate.then.catch.err (C:\Users\Mi\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:275:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'ECONNCLOSED', name: 'ConnectionError' }

Comment: this is my very first attemp in node.js.. I assume that i may have done a dumb mistake, or so?

Comment: Code looks to be fine. I believe, the main issue is with your connection to mssql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a node router to redirect the request in `/` which is missing on your code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
/*other code*/
//create a router for /
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select * from testtable', function(err, recordset) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: we put a table name inside the router.get('/testtable', function (req, res), but this didn't work...do you mean that?